# Error : Starting POSTGRESQL server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, postgresql-9.1

i am very new to ruby and postgresql.
When i try to run

```
ruby scrpit/server, rake db:migrate, rake db:seed
```

i get this.

```
Rails 2.3.11 application starting on http:/0.0.0.0:3000  
warning: already initialized constant SESSION_SECRET  
Faraday: you may want to install system_timer for reliable timeouts  
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371/gems/activerecord-.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:941:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PGError)  

Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting  
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I am on ubuntu 12.04, ruby 1.8.7, rails-2.3, gem 1.5.3

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do:

verify that postgres server is actually running

```
$ netstat -a | grep postgre
```

if its running, try connecting to it from terminal using `psql` command. incase its, not running. try starting it manually

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

If it still doesn't start, 
Are there any error messages in the server.log? If yes do post them here.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I tried both of these,but none of them worked. Here is the error message.'http://pastebin.com/jwVB3NaS

Comment: -Error:The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgres-xc : Depends: postgres-xc-client but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.